# System/Integration Testing a Flask Web application

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-web-services, integration-testing, system-testing

I have a web application which uses Flask and talks to a database at the backend. It also uses Amazon AWS S3. I have written unit tests for this package.

The question is that I want to write integration tests where I am testing the external dependencies as well. I have been reading about integration tests and system tests. Do I create a new package lets says FooSystemTests or FooIntegrationTests or should they be part of my application package? I am planning to make this as part of my deployment process.  My plan was in the integration tests I will test my external dependencies and in the system tests I will test things like if I go to a route what do I get back (testing as if the system is a black box). Also I read about selenium testing, where should that be system or integration?

Any thoughts/ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: Do you intend to test the front-end as well? If your is "no" I think you can perform a regular test invoking your entry calls. Even if you want to simulate a navigation you can do that using "requests" or "curl".That should be enough, no?

Comment: @Menegazzo Yes, I want to test the front-end also

Comment: I really don't like Selenium for many (personal) reasons. Here where I work we use Jasmine to write the front-end tests and Karma to run them.